# .NET alternative to Google Checkout

Tags: asp.net, google-checkout

Our .NET website uses Google Checkout to handle credit card processing and we need to migrate to another credit card service because Google Checkout is going away. Google Checkout used a .NET webcontrol that was easy to use and did not require that our site actually capture the credit card on a SSL site.

Does anyone recommend a replacement for this type of service that is easy to integrate using ASP.NET and leaves the security to them? Google provided a link to Braintree in their announcement but when I looked at that, it looked like we have to capture the credit card info. I'd prefer not to have the risk.

Comment: I suppose you did not hear PayPal.

Comment: Paypal isn't a credit card

Comment: The google checkout, was start as alternative to PayPal. PP includes credit card and transparent payment. I also know and work with the MoneyBookers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aristos has mentioned, you can look into PayPal and/or [Amazon Checkout](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business/cba).

Both of them provide alternative/3rd party **checkout** services - which is what Google *Checkout* is (*was* after November 2013).

Braintree is a **payment processor** and is very different from Google Checkout and any other *checkout* services - they offer **credit card processing** services (just like Authorize.net, Paypal Payflow, etc.). You will need to have/apply for a *merchant account* and comply with PCI DSS requirements when using such services (although they have services that minimize your PCI DSS work).

Google Wallet for Online Commerce (aka "Instant Buy") is a "layer" on top of such - which is the Google product/service that will "assume" the role of the *"payment flow"* (I hesitate to call it a "payment service" as it's really **not**) for merchants selling *physical goods*. It will work with (in fact *require*) your **existing payment processor**.

Wallet for Digital (aka "In-App Payment"), as the name implies, is the digital (product/service) counterpart of "Instant Buy". This is *still a 3rd party checkout service* - meaning it's still Google that handles the credit card processing (just like Checkout does/did). But it's primarily for digital merchants (selling digital products).